# Service with AlarmManager

Tags: android

I have an App which doing stuff in a Service in background (also when Screen is swiched off). I start the service in an Activity which following code.

```
Intent i=new Intent(this, AppService.class);
i.putExtra(AppService.VOL_ALM, amanager.getStreamVolume(amanager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM)));

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);  
alarmManager.cancel(pi);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 *60, pi);
```

The code in trhe Service looks like this:

```
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    test = intent.getIntExtra(VOL_ALM, 0);


    timer = new Timer("TweetCollectorTimer");
    timer.schedule(updateTask, 0, 15 * 1000L);

    return(START_NOT_STICKY);
  }
```

In the Service I have to change the variable "test" and work with it. But I always lose the changed value of the variable because onStartCommand sometimes executed. I tried to store the variable with preferences, but I also need the original value of the variable when I start the service. 
The best way would be changing the data "VOL_ALM" from the intend in a Method. But is that possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can persist an array to the SharedPreferences and recreate with `System.arraycopy(...)`. (0 - 1st VOL_ARM, 1 - 2nd VOL_ARM) ... O(n)...eh.:(.. Before using it to crate/recreate a list for each "alarm event", I would consider architecture changes - like IPC Messages and have the service deal with the message.

Answer (score 1):

?

Store both values in SharedPreferences? That's the accepted method for persisting values.

Comment: The problem is when I restart the service I need the data from the Intent. But when the service is running in background onStartCommand() is sometimes called. I dont know the difference from start the service and running in background because onStartCommand is called on both situations.

Comment: @user1390816: Load the data from the backing store in `onCreate()` of your service.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think this should work. I delete the preferences in onCreate() and load it in onStartCommand(). I will post if it worked.